# Why am I not able to login to Azure using power shell commands that are being executed from ASP.Net code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, powershell, runspace

I have created an ASP.Net Web application. From this application, I am trying to execute power shell commands to log in to Azure. The command being used is 'az login'. When I run the application, I get proper response that is expected from a login command, the response tells me that the login is successful. The problem though, is that when I host the same application in IIS, I don't get the expected result, instead I get an empty response which indicates that there is some problem. Below is the code that I am using:

```
        Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
        runspace.Open();
        Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
        pipeline.Commands.AddScript("az login -u vtripathi@hsdyn.com -p ********");
        pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");
        var output = pipeline.Invoke();
        string result = output[0].ToString();
```

Please suggest what might be wrong.

Comment: Are you getting any error / exception ?

Comment: @ManojChoudhari, no errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to do with the application pool identity.

Change application pool identity to your account instead of default and it should work.

Comment: This worked after changing application pool identity.

Comment: I have another question though, but may be I should ask a separate question on stack overflow. I need to deploy this application on Azure, I need to know what settings need to be applied on Azure to get this working.